# Getting numbers from an array using mask and regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Having this array with `code` and `collection`, where `X` is a mask that can be "any number":

```
input_array = [{"code": "XXXX10", "collection": "one"}, {"code": "XXX610", "collection": "two"}, {"code": "XXXX20", "collection": "three"}]
```

I want a function that given any 6 digit code, for example `000710` returns the value that matches the *best* code mask (for the example would be `one`). This is my try:

```
def get_collection_from_code(analysis_code):
    for collection in input_array:
        actual_code = collection["code"]
        mask_to_re = actual_code.replace("X", "[\d\D]")
        pattern = re.compile("^" + mask_to_re + "$")
        if pattern.match(analysis_code):
            print("Found collection '" + str(collection["collection"]) + "' for code: " + str(analysis_code))
            return collection["collection"]
        
res = get_collection_from_code("010610")
print(res)
```

The problem here is that if I inpuit the code `010610` (and I want to return `two`), it returns `one` as also matches the pattern `XXXX10` first.

For better understanding, if I input there values, I would like to have those ouputs:

```
010610 > two
010010 > one
123420 > three
```

Comment: what makes a code mask the best? instead of returning instantly, keep a variable of the current best and return it at the end of the loop

Comment: also, the variable input shadows the function input()

Comment: best = more numbers mattching the mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the entire collection, saving the length of the "X" part of any match, and then return the shortest:

```py
input_array = [{"code": "XXXX10", "collection": "one"}, {"code": "XXX610", "collection": "two"}, {"code": "XXXX20", "collection": "three"}]   

def get_collection_from_code(analysis_code):
    results = {}
    for collection in input:
        actual_code = collection["code"]
        mask_to_re = actual_code.replace("X", "[\d\D]")
        pattern = re.compile("^" + mask_to_re + "$")
        if pattern.match(analysis_code):
            results[collection["collection"]] = actual_code.count('X')
    if len(results):
        best = sorted(results.items(), key=lambda i:i[1])[0]
        print("Found collection '" + str(best[0]) + "' for code: " + str(analysis_code))
        return best[0]

res = get_collection_from_code("010610")
# Found collection 'two' for code: 010610
```

Note I've saved all the matches in case you want to process them in any way. Otherwise you could just check for the "best" match in each iteration and update that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom function to count the number of matches

```
inpt = '000710'

# rework the list of dictionaries into a {code: collection} dict
tmp = {d['code']: d['collection'] for d in input_array}

def n_matches(A, B):
    return sum(a==b for a, b in zip(A, B))

out = tmp[max(tmp, key=lambda x: n_matches(x, inpt))]
```

Output:

```
#inpt = '000710'
'one'

#inpt = '010610'
'two'

#inpt = '123420'
'three'
```

Comment: dont we already know the count of the matches? do we need a function for it?

Comment: @ellieff1493 I assumed that the numbers do not necessarily match.

Answer (score 0):

You could create variables to keep track of the best match and return the corresponding collection. Also, you could compare lengths to prioritize matches based on the number of fixed digits in the code.

```
def get_collection_from_code(analysis_code):

    best_match = None
    best_match_collection = None

    for collection in input_data:
        actual_code = collection["code"]
        mask_to_re = actual_code.replace("X", "[\d\D]")
        pattern = re.compile("^" + mask_to_re + "$")

        if pattern.match(analysis_code):
            if best_match is None or len(actual_code.replace("X", "")) > len(best_match.replace("X", "")):
                best_match = actual_code
                best_match_collection = collection["collection"]

    if best_match_collection is not None:
        print("Found collection '" + str(best_match_collection) + "' for code: " + str(analysis_code))
        return best_match_collection
```

Answer (score 0):

sort the array so the first match is the best match.

```
input_array.sort(key=lambda x: x["code"].count("X"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option would be to compute the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)*imum* [`ratio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio) of a [`SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) :

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def get_collection_from_code(analysis_code):
    return max(input_array,
        key=lambda d: SequenceMatcher(
            None, d["code"].replace("X", "0"), analysis_code).ratio()
        )["collection"]
```

Output :

```
for c in ["010610", "010010", "123420"]:
    print(c, "=>", get_collection_from_code(c))
    
010610 => two
010010 => one
123420 => three
```

Intermediates :

```
'XXXX10' one   '010610' 0.5
'XXX610' two   '010610' 0.83 # << highest
'XXXX20' three '010610' 0.5

'XXXX10' one   '010010' 0.83 # << highest
'XXX610' two   '010010' 0.67
'XXXX20' three '010010' 0.5

'XXXX10' one   '123420' 0.17
'XXX610' two   '123420' 0.17
'XXXX20' three '123420' 0.33 # << highest
```

Answer (score 0):

If the query function `get_collection_from_code` is to be called more than once, a more efficient approach to performing the query in *O(1)* time complexity would be to sort the input codes by the number of `X`s first, join them into one alternation pattern with each sub-pattern enclosed in a capture group, and create a list of collections sorted in the same order, so that you can simply obtain the collection from a given input code using the index of the capture group in the match:

```
import re
from operator import itemgetter

input = [
    {"code": "XXXX10", "collection": "one"},
    {"code": "XXX610", "collection": "two"},
    {"code": "XXXX20", "collection": "three"}
]
sorted_input = sorted(
    map(itemgetter('code', 'collection'), input),
    key=lambda t: t[0].count('X')
)
code_pattern = re.compile(
    '|'.join(
        f"({code.replace('X', '.')})"
        for code, _ in sorted_input
    )
)
collections = [collection for _, collection in sorted_input]

def get_collection_from_code(analysis_code):
    if match := code_pattern.fullmatch(analysis_code):
        return collections[match.lastindex - 1] # capture group is 1-based
```

so that:

```
print(get_collection_from_code('010610'))
print(get_collection_from_code('010010'))
print(get_collection_from_code('123420'))
```

outputs:

```
two
one
three
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/MLFmSY